# List of reasons that this error can occur: OAuth2::Error, invalid_grant: AADSTS65001

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, office365

We have implemented Microsoft Azure oauth2 on our web app, and we are trying to address common errors that users have when using that oauth method.

The error: **OAuth2::Error, invalid_grant: AADSTS65001: No permission to access user information is configured for '...' application, or it is expired or revoked.** resembles about 82% of our errors with the azure oauth flow.

Here's our configuration:

```
# ==> Office 365 OAuth2
config.omniauth :azure_oauth2,
  client_id: '...',
  client_secret: '...',
  tenant_id: '...',
  resource: 'https://outlook.office365.com/',
  setup: lambda { |env|
    params = Rack::Utils.parse_query(env['QUERY_STRING'])
    options = env['omniauth.strategy'].options

    case params['state']
    when 'calendar'
      options[:prompt] = 'login'
    when 'select_account'
      options[:prompt] = 'login'
    end 
  }
```

**We know** that this error *can* be caused from using a non Office 365 account.  Since our resource is 'https://outlook.office365.com/', and because our app needs to be able to interact with your calendar, the user must authenticate with an office 365 account.  Some other account like a microsoft live account will cause this error.

**QUESTIONS**

1 - what else might cause this error?

2 - Is there a way to limit the azure oauth flow to only allow true office 365 logins?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is: If a user got locked out and had to reset his password or any other invalid tries to login to Azure AD (Which authenticates users against o365) will invalidate the refresh token that your app has. therefore, an application will handle the changed password (old refresh token) gracefully by throwing this error. In this case, you app should redirect the user to the authorization page to authenticate the user.

Hope this helps.

Comment: We are seeing this error when the user doesn't have an invalid credential, when a brand new user is able to login to their mail - and they come and authorize us, and we know they have a real office365 subscription.

Super common, and can't find anything to correlate to. Right now we just tell people: "Sorry, some Microsoft accounts give us an error and Microsoft will not tell us why. Looks like you can't use our service unfortunately."

up at night crying over this